# java Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, arrays

i defined a constant array of percentiles. I need the same values in different classes. So i want to define once

```
public class ABC {
   public static final double[] PERCENTILES = {0.5, 0.80, 0.90, 0.95, 0.99};
   ...
}
```

i used the array in `@Timed` in a different class

```
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
public class XYZ{
  @Timed(value = "..", percentiles = ABC.PERCENTILES)
  public void tmp(){
     ...
  }
}
```

I have an error:

ABC.PERCENTILES -> `Attribute value must be constant`

Comment: I saw in https://www.baeldung.com/timed-metrics-aspectj that `@Timed` uses `name` attribute. Is it that case? And what if replace the constant with a real value (`percentiles = ...`)?

Comment: @CoolMind i used a different library. See my updates.

Comment: Sadly that's simply not possible in Java. You'd have to write `percentiles = {0.5, 0.80, 0.90, 0.95, 0.99}`

Comment: i need the same values in different classes. So i want to define once